# $scope.$parent returns null when reaching .success

Tags: angularjs

So I have a childCtrl that has a function that adds a customer, after successfully adding it updates to it's parent's controller. But when I reach promise.success $scope.parent is null. Why is this happening?

```
    $scope.addCustomer = function ( user ) {
        console.log( $scope.$parent ) //returns childscope object
        $scope.submitted = true;

        if ( $scope.addfrm.$valid ) {
            var newCustomer = JSON.stringify( user );
            customersFactory
            .addCustomer( newCustomer )
            .then( function ( data ) {
                console.log($scope.$parent) // returns null
                $scope.$parent.customers.push( data ); //returns error because $scope.$parent is null
                $scope.$parent.custLength = $scope.$parent.customers.length; //returns error because $scope.$parent is null
            } );
            $modalInstance.close();
        }
    };
```

my github for full reference: github.com/xxryan1234/angularCustomerManagement

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for this ?

Comment: I don't have a fiddle, but this is my github repository https://github.com/xxryan1234/angularCustomerManagement addCustomerController.js is the file @themyth92

Comment: Maybe you close the modal before return promise. Try to put the line $modalInstance.close(); inside the function(data) as well. Put it below the $scope.$parent.custLength = $scope.$parent.customers.length;

Comment: you are right, it's because of $modalInstance.close(); I tried putting this inside the function as you've said but this still gives me $scope.$parent to null. How do I close the modal if I cant call $modalInstance.close();?

Comment: You can do something like this http://jsfiddle.net/themyth92/oc0s4d4h/. I use $timeout to replace the $http service but it should work the same way. Furthermore, you can put some loading icon on the modal when you start to send data from client to server to let the user know the data is processing and remove it inside your promise when the data come back. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! I got it to work now. @themyth92 I did your first suggestion trying to move the modalinstance.close after updating my scope. it's weird because when I console.log the scope, it returns null on my $scope.$parent but I don't get the exception anymore.

Comment: When you close your modal, the $scope inside modal will be destroyed, so I think promise can not get the $scope reference and return some exception. When you do it inside promise, it updates the data first before destroy it so maybe you not get any exception. About the $scope.$parent return null, I am not sure why. But I suggest you should not update the parent scope inside your promise but do it inside the bootstrap modal promise as I do on the fiddle. With bootstrap modal, many cases you will not get the parent controller scope by just $scope.$parent. Sometimes, it will be rootscope.

Comment: Thank you so much for the knowledge you have given me kind sir @themyth92 I wish you would post answer so I could accept it right away would add more points to you!